# Cocoa Application Display Combo Box with a format based on Text Field input

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, combobox, cocoa-bindings

I am new to Mac application. I have form in which there is a combo box and text field. User can enter text values, and based upon the text input value, the combo box value need to be changed. i.e., the data source of combo box will be updated each time, when the text input changes. The combo box lists various formats with dd_mm_yyyy_textfieldinputname, mm__dd_yyyy_textfieldinputname, textfieldinputname_dd_mm_yyyy etc. 
Can I do this using objective C. i.e., here the Combobox input changes based on the values of user input text field dynamically.

Comment: I don't understand the question, what should happen and when? What have you tried?

Comment: @Willeke the combo contents need to be changed based on the text field input values.

Comment: The bindings will take care of that. Just change the content of the array controller.